# Report generator only showing names of the objects instead of their content

Tags: matlab, report, reportgenerator

I have a code generating a full report but I want to add an image in the header so I created a template and tried out. But now the word file only gives me the name of the objects in the report and not the actual content like this:
[image]

Do anyone know where does this problem comes from?
My code is

```
%% init
import mlreportgen.report.*
import mlreportgen.dom.*

rpt = Document('Report','docx', 'template.dotx');
moveToNextHole(rpt)

%% chapter
ChapterRegression = Chapter;
ChapterRegression.Title = 'Summary';

append(rpt, ChapterRegression)

close(rpt)
rptview(rpt)
```

My `dotx` template just have one `Rich Text Content Control` hole.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you narrow down the possibilities with a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also be sure to show the section of code causing the problem.

Comment: Aside, I may as well make a preemptive comment. For generating templated documents, you may be much better off using latex.

Comment: @Argyll Well I shortened the code to only the chapter and I get the same thing as before, and I honestly have no idea what section of the code causes the problem..

Comment: @Argyll is LaTex the default template of the Matlab Report Generator? Because currently that's the one I am using. However I just wanted to add a logo on my pages and that's why I'm trying what's above

Comment: I am happy to debug a little with you. But is there something unique to your `report.docx` and `template.dotx` files? Could you provide a link to minimal example files (or write them in the question)?

Comment: For Matlab Report Generator, I know it's a sort of interface between raw matlab code and a presentable report. Mathwork has been going along that route for ages. And I've given up on following that idea a long time ago. What exactly do you need? What I do for my articles/reports is that I write the report in Latex. Whenever data or plot is involved, they are generated elsewhere. Latex lets you link them and refreshes each time any change is made. Also certain sections -- mainly tables -- of latex code is generated elsewhere. That 'elsewhere' is usually Matlab for me.

Comment: @Argyll actually I found my answer on another forum, let me answer my own question!

Comment: Sounds good. Way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been answered on [Mathwork forum](https://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/473437-report-only-showing-names-of-the-objects-instead-of-their-content?s_tid=prof_contriblnk). But let me sum it up here as well:

I am using the `Document` object and we can not add Report API objects like TitlePage to a DOM Document. Instead and that was what I was doing at first I should use  `mlreportgen.report.Report` of the DOM Document. You can add both DOM and Report API objects to a Report object.

Then to use all the functions relative to the `Document` object like `moveToNextHole()` the `Report` object has an underlying DOM Document object that can be used.
Use it like this for example:

```
doc = rpt.Document;
doc.moveToNextHole();
```